# nspredicate iphone question

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4, nspredicate

i have the following code

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Word== %@", randomWord];
rows = [[courseArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]retain];
```

I am using this in a search bar. I have two questions - how can i make the NSPredicate so it takes every word that begins with the characters typed rather than having a value equal another? e.g I have "Men, Many,Morons, Now,Never" in the array,  and when i type "M" i want "Men,Many,Morons" to be added. Furthermore, how can i predicate more than 1 value? so it compares between two formats?

thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Try
`NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Word BEGINSWITH %@", randomWord];`

If you want to search the whole word you can try `CONTAINS`..

Answer (score 1):

The [NSPredicate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) documentation is a good place to start.

The predicate to check if the string begins with another is `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Word BEGINSWITH %@"]`

And as far as checking two predicates, you're looking for `NSCompoundPredicate`.

Answer (score 1):

You need create all of the predicate which you want to compare and append all predicate to array. after that you can use `NSCompoundPredicate` for `or`,`and` condition.

like that

```
NSPredicate *finalPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"is_neutered = 0"],
    [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubPredicates:feedDays]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html

Look for the 'Prefix' part under the String Constants, Variables, and Wildcards section.